# Warning: call_user_func() expects parameter 1 to be a valid callback

Tags: themes, actions, theme-options, settings-api

This my code:

```
$array_theme_options = array(
    array(
        'id' => 'facebook_url',
        'title' => 'Facebook Profile Url',
        'callback' => 'display_facebook_element',
        'page' => 'theme-options',
        'type' => 'text'
    )
);


function input_type($id, $type)
{
    switch ($type) {
        case 'text':
            $input = '<input type="text" name="' . $id . '" id="facebook_url" value="' . get_option($id) . '" />';
        break;
        case 'checkbox':
            $input = '<input type="checkbox" name="' . $id . '" value="1" '.checked(1, get_option($id), true). ' />';
        break;
    }
    return $input;
}



function display_theme_panel_fields()
{
    global $array_theme_options;
    add_settings_section("section", "All Settings", null, "theme-options");

    foreach ($array_theme_options as $ato) {
        $cf = create_function('$id, $type','return input_type($id, $type);');
        $input_type = $cf($ato['id'], $ato['type']);

        add_settings_field($ato['id'], $ato['title'], $input_type, $ato['page'], "section");
        register_setting("section", $ato['id']);
    }
}
add_action("admin_init", "display_theme_panel_fields");
```

And i get this error with input
[image]

Comment: What is the function name you blanked out?

Answer (score 0):

You have not defined a function called `display_facebook_element`, at least you did not include that in the code posted. Thus, you are getting the error. `display_facebook_element` isn't a valid callback. It doesn't exist.

Comment: I'm sorry but I do not understand you
I do not use `Display_facebook_element` because I'm using with `Create_function`

Comment: Help please, I believe it is a simple solution